# React Native - RealmJS - Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, macos

React Native application is throwing the following error when building in Xcode. I am building on Mac M1.

Undefined symbols:
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried pod install after removing the Pods folder. It doesn't seem to help.

The code builds file in android.

React Native : 11.3.10
Node: v18.18.0
iOS: 17

additional errors in build

vtable for facebook::jsi::JSIException, referenced from:
facebook::jsi::JSError::JSError(facebook::jsi::JSError const&) in librealm-js-ios.a[arm64]3
vtable for facebook::jsi::JSError, referenced from:
facebook::jsi::JSError::JSError(facebook::jsi::JSError const&) in librealm-js-ios.a[arm64]3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tried deleting the Pods folder and the pod install.

Removed the node_modules and reinstalled all dependencies.

Nothing seems to work.